# Zener diode as clamp in output of comparator not working

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, zener, comparator

I'm trying to have the output of my comparator be either 0 or 5 V.

I'm using an [LM311P](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/157724/TI/LM311P.html) comparator supplied with 24 V-0 V. At COL_EMIT, I'm using a Zener diode of 5V1 to impose 5.1 V as the maximum on that node, but the output I'm getting at COL_EMIT is 0 V and 24 mV.

My signal V2 is about 0.4 Vpp, but I expect the clamp effect should make it 5 V (since it's providing 24 V to the comparator and has pull-up resistor to 24 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fItnGy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you really using 100 ohms resistor there?

Comment: V2 is referenced to the negative rail, so the non-inverting input is being driven below the negative rail when V2 is negative. Do you mean to reference V2 to VGND?

Comment: @EdinFifić I'm sorry, it is 10KR. My mistake for not changing it

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to get the LM311 to work with a 400mV peak signal and no negative supply. To shift the inputs to within the common-mode range of the IC I've used two 10K+10K voltage dividers. In reality you might want to use a pair that provided a common mode voltage closer to 1 or 2V rather than 12V since errors in the resistor ratio will cause an offset that could add up to a significant part of your 400mV (eg. with 1% resistors worst-case mismatch is about +/-240mV. Still functional with a 400mV signal but not ideal.

[image]

Another approach would be to split the 24V with an op-amp buffer as so:

[image]

Of course with AC coupling it won't work all the way down to DC. If you add a negative supply such as -5V for the comparator it will work with both inputs near 0V and down to DC.

Answer (score 3):

If your input signal is 0.4 volts p-p no way will it exceed the threshold of 12 volts shown in your circuit diagram (I added the purple bits): -

[image]

Hence, the output stays low. But, your input is also running significantly beyond the recommended operating conditions: -

[image]

If the input is 0.4 volts p-p centred on 0 volts (which is also the negative rail for the device), then all bets are off regarding performance. In fact the absolute limits for the input do not permit it to go negative with respect to the negative rail so, your device could become damaged. Your pull-up on the collector is far too low as well.

Answer (score 2):

100\$\Omega\$ is too low a value for the pullup resistor at 24 V. The transistor in the LM311 is only rated for 50 mA, that resistor will allow it to be four times that. The resistor would also dissipate a good bit of power, around 3.5 W with the output high, over 5 W with it low (for as long as the transistor holds up at Ic = ~230 mA). If you have it connected as the schematic shows and are getting that low of a voltage at COL_EMIT I would suspect that the resistor is fried, the transistor is fried, or both.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change that resistor value. It's 10KR, not 100 Ohms. The 100Ohms was the standard value for the CircuitLab and I forgot to change to 10K